# Sqlite3.Binary gives TypeError: buffer object expected

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a list which I extracted from a txt file as follows:

```
authors = re.match('#@(.*)', line)
if authors:
   authors_list = authors.group(1).split(",")
```

Now I need to insert these into my database, which should be done as follows:

```
for a in authors_list:
    c.execute("INSERT INTO authors(Name) VALUES (?)", (a))
```

But when I do that I get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 17 supplied.
```

So I did some research and found that I should change my variable a into a tuple (a, ) as such:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO authors(Name) VALUES (?)", (a,))
```

And I also tried this:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO authors(Name) VALUES (?)", ((a,)))
```

But got the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

So I did more research and found that I should use sqlite3's Binary function. So I tried the following:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO authors(Name) VALUES (?)", (sqlite3.Binary((a,))))
```

And got the following error:

```
TypeError: buffer object expected
```

I keep going back and forth between all three errors no mater what combination I try. Any help would be appreciated. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in a tuple, not a bytestring:

```
sqlite3.Binary((a,))
```

Create a tuple with the *result* of `sqlite3.Binary()`, having passed in *just* `a`:

```
(sqlite3.Binary(a),)
```

The whole statement is then run as:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO authors(Name) VALUES (?)",
          (sqlite3.Binary(a),))
```

However, if this is supposed to be *text*, you'd normally *decode* the bytes to a string instead of trying to insert binary data:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO authors(Name) VALUES (?)",
          (a.decode('utf8'),))
```

This does assume that your text is encoded using the UTF-8 codec; adjust the decoding as needed to match your data.

Comment: The worked beautifully! Thanks Martijn. :) I don't know why I didn't see that!